# Magneto 2 : remove attribute from particular configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, remove

ex. I have a configurable product id X
having attributes like color, size, material,A,B,C etc. and I want to remove attribute C from the product X.

and also remove from every linked products with X.
I have attached a SS here.

[image]

This delete button is on product view page of configurable product X.
and it has child products P,Q,R.

if I remove color green then all linked product with size like, 
size S-green, L- green, M-green should remove.

likewise, If I remove 'specification' attribute, it will remove from configuration and linked simple products(P,Q,R) too.

can anyone help me on this ? 
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Have you tried with any code, or you just need the ready made code?

Comment: so you want to remove from admin, right?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel yes, from admin side.

Comment: so please go in attribute section and remove it, or else you want?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel no not like that. I have delete button and I want to delete attribute programatically.

Comment: okay, so you have added delete button in admin and when you click it you need to delete it from every where? right?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel yes right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104741/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-dimple-panchal).